# universal quatifier in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project for my database class to make a database for a group of libraries. I am using MySQL 5.2. I have to write a query to find the two libraries that hold copies of every book.  these are the create table statements

```
Create table books(  
    booknum VARCHAR (10),  
    btitle VARCHAR (),  
    bpages SMALLINT,  
    bcdate DATE,  
    primary key (booknum))  

Create table copies(  
    cnum VARCHAR(12),  
    cprice DECIMAL (7,2),  
   cpurdate DATE,  
    booknum VARCHAR(10),  
    primary key (cnum),  
    foreign key (booknum)  
    references book(booknum)) 

Create table library(  
    libnum  VARCHAR(7),  
    libname VARCHAR (40),  
    streetNumber    VARCHAR (8),  
    streetName VARCHAR (20),  
    city VARCHAR (20),  
    state VARCHAR (2),  
    zipcode VARCHAR (5),  
    primary key (libnum))
```

I believe I need a something like

```
SELECT libname FROM libraries WHERE  NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM copies C, books B WHERE C.booknum=B.booknum)
```

but thats not it?

Comment: Side note - For some reason, all SQL newbies attempt to solve everything with subqueries. My advice is that you learn to use and love the `JOIN` operator family.

Comment: I don't see how `library` and `copies` are connected. BTW it's a good habit to call all your primary tables with a singular noun for the entity they contain, somehow worse is to use plurals, but having _both_ plurals and singulars is unreasonable at best.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: sub-queries aren't evil. And a JOIN is usually not a drop-in replacement for a sub-query. And besides any decent query optimizer will rewrite the query anyway into the most efficient (and equivalent) condition.

Comment: Oh i forgot to add the foreign key from copies to libraries

Answer (score 0):

Your database design is incomplete.  You need to add another table that defines a many to many relationship between copies and libraries.

Comment: Or at least add a field to copies referencing library.  The copies table seem to be the table that defines many to many relationships between books and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

**After you have updated your tables by adding foreign key from libraries to copies table ...**

```
SELECT b.btitle, l.libname from copies c left join books b on b.booknum = c.booknum
    left join l.libnum = c.libnum
```